# Getting a error for my Minecraft plugin and cant figure out how to solve it

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I am currently creating a plugin where a random thing happens every 60 seconds and when I was about to build the first test an error came up it's in line 73 and about the part where it says "this" I cannot figure out how to fix it any and all help would be appreciated!

The Error : java: incompatible types:  cannot be converted to org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin

Here is my code:

```
package com.zoren3105.Chaos;


import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.Material;

import org.bukkit.entity.EntityType;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.potion.PotionEffect;
import org.bukkit.potion.PotionEffectType;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitRunnable;


import java.util.Random;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        //Fired when the server enables the plugin
        runnable();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        //Fired when the server stops and disables all plugins
    }




    Random rand = new Random();

    public void runnable() {

        new BukkitRunnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                for(Player p : getServer().getOnlinePlayers()) ;
                Player player = (Player) Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers();

                int chance = rand.nextInt(50);
                if (chance == 0) {
                    player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.ABSORPTION, 60, 2));
                } else if (chance == 1) {
                    player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.POISON, 60, 2));
                } else if (chance == 2) {
                    player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.BLINDNESS, 60, 2));
                } else if (chance == 3) {
                    player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.SPEED, 60, 60));
                } else if (chance == 4) {
                    player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.JUMP, 60, 10));
                } else if (chance == 5) {
                    player.getInventory().addItem(new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND));
                } else if (chance == 6) {
                    player.getInventory().addItem(new ItemStack(Material.STICK));
                } else if (chance == 7) {
                    player.setHealth(1);
                } else if (chance == 8) {
                    player.getWorld().spawnEntity((Location) player, EntityType.CREEPER);
                } else if (chance == 9) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                        player.getWorld().spawnEntity((Location) player, EntityType.PRIMED_TNT);
                    }
                } else if (chance == 10) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                        player.getWorld().spawnEntity((Location) player, EntityType.ARROW);
                    }
                }runTaskTimerAsynchronously(this, 600, 600);
            }
        };

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` in that position references the `BukkitRunnable()`, not your `Main` class. You can fix this by passing a reference to your `Plugin` like so

```java
public void runnable(Plugin plugin) {
   ...
   }runTaskTimerAsynchronously(plugin, 600, 600);
}
```

And then call it like so

```java
runnable(this);
```

However, your code won't work; likely for a few reasons, but one that I see is that your for loop has an empty body

```java
for(Player p : getServer().getOnlinePlayers()) ;
```

Which I think you assume gives you a player as you then cast the results of [`getOnlinePlayers()`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/Server.html#getOnlinePlayers()) to a `Player` which will not work as the method returns `Collection<? extends Player>`. You will benefit from taking a Java course; Spigot has a [basic tutorial on their wiki](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/spigot-plugin-development/) which can also help.